# Remove drawer default divider in flutter

Tags: flutter, drawer, divider

I'm trying to remove a divider that is showed by default in the drawer under the drawer header shown in this image (It arrived with the 3.16 flutter version) :
[Drawer divider image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m81Or.png)

I tried following this post answers : [Flutter DrawerHeader // How to get rid of divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531281/flutter-drawerheader-how-to-get-rid-of-divider)

But it didn't work and created another divider on top of the current : [Drawer with red divider on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEpLC.png)

Here is my drawer code (not complete only with the drawer header part) :

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  User? currentUser = Auth().currentUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      elevation: 20,
      backgroundColor: Colpal.purple,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 290,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              child: Column(children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pop(context), 
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colpal.white,)
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(uid: currentUser!.uid.toString(),),));
                            
                          },
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/export_icons/icons/iconUser.svg", height: 137,),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(uid: currentUser!.uid.toString(),),));
                        
                      },
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 137,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Center(
                          child: profilePicture(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
          
                verticalSpacer(20),
                StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(  
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData){
                      final userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      if (userData['username']!=null){
                        return Text(
                          userData['username'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: Colpal.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                          ),
                        );
                      }else{
                        return Text(
                          S.of(context).yourProfile,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: Colpal.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colpal.white),
                    );
                },)
              ],)
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I answered there. I honestly think that this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76638971/12195695

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this didn't helped. I still have a white divider under the one created with the box decoration : https://imgur.com/a/lLQuwL5

Comment: I see what you are talking about but, I still believe if you go through my answer, it is exactly what you are looking for. If you still experience your issue, share your code for the updated drawer which follows the instruction in that answer

Comment: I removed the drawer header and it works it's not perfect but I'll go with it thank you for the answer